# Does the following classification of stationary points work for $n \geq 3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

As we see, the upper works for $n = 2$, but does it work for higher dimensions. How would we classify stationary points there ?

Answer (score 0):

For a multivariate problem the equivalent of the second derivative test is to look at whether the Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second-derivative_test)